# Rotate of 2d array matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a two dimensional array that I need to rotate 90 degrees.

My current solution is like this, any other methods ?

```js
const matrix=([[1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]])

const transpose = matrix => {
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
       for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          const tmp = matrix[i][j];
          matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
          matrix[j][i] = tmp;
       };
    }
 }
 transpose(matrix);
 reverse=matrix.map(row=>row.reverse())

 for (let i in reverse) {
    console.log(...reverse[i] );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it:

```
const matrix=([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]]);

let newMatrix= new Array();

for (let j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++){
    newMatrix.push([]);
    for (let i = matrix.length-1; i >-1; i--){
        newMatrix[j].push(matrix[i][j]);
    };
};

console.log(newMatrix); // output: [ [ 7, 4, 1 ], [ 8, 5, 2 ], [ 9, 6, 3 ] ]
```